# Button a button unclickabale in Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm trying to develop a Quiz App, I have a main menu with all the levels, I would like that when a level is finished make it's button in the main menu go unclickable..

Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: button.setEnabled(false);   or button.setOnClickListener(null);

Comment: i've tried button.clickable(false); but when how to tell that the quiz is finisehd...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have five question. when he reached the last question. He definetly submit or click next. on that just pass a boolean variable in Intent if it is in an other Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Destination.class);

intent.putExtra("flag",true/False);

startActivity(intent);
```

getting intent in another activity..

```
boolean flag = getIntent.getExtra().getBoolean("flag");

if(flag)
//  button.setEnabled(false);

else 

// do other stuff
```

// to send and recieve boolean

Set intent extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("yourBoolName", true);
```

Retrieve intent extra:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
}
```

Comment: the getting intent in another activity isn't working.

Comment: Sorry i forget to add getBoolean.. now see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in defined button object in this method set

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
button.setEnabled(false);